# Ajax jquery.min.js:4 POST 500 (Internal Server Error) JSP Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to call a JSP Page from javascript . I am doing it by ajax request.

My ajax part is as following :

```
 btn.onclick = function() {
            var dataString = 'functionName=getFileName';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "database_connections.jsp",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                    counterPdf = 0;
                    var fileName = result.split(",");
                    var d1 = document.getElementById('modal-body');
                    document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = "";
                    for (i = 1; i < fileName.length; i++) {
                        // d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p onclick=\"getFileName(this);\">' + fileName[i] + '</p>');
                        d1.innerHTML += '<p onclick=\"getFileName(this);\">' + fileName[i] + '</p>';
                        //   d1.innerHTML += "<YOUR_CONTENT>"; 
                    }
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                }
            }); 
        }
```

My jsp page is as following :

```
<%-- 
    Document   : database_connections
    Created on : Mar 1, 2017, 10:45:02 AM
    Author     : Sultan
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page language="java" import ="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@page language="java" import ="java.io.IOException" %> 
<%@page language="java" import ="j java.io.InputStream " %> 
<%@page language="java" import ="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils *" %> 
<%@page language="java" import =" java.io.StringWriter " %> 



<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>  

<%!


%>

<%
    String functionName = request.getParameter("functionName");
    out.println(functionName);   

    if(functionName.equals("create_new_file"))
    {

    }
    else if(functionName.equals("getFileName"))
    {

    }
    else if(functionName.equals("getFileContent"))
    { 

    }
    else if(functionName.equals("saveFileContent"))
    {

    }
    else if(functionName.equals("saveToPdf"))
    {

    } 
%>
```

But when I am clicking the button , I am getting the following error in console.

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8084/DocumentEditor/database_connections.jsp 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4
```

Why am I getting this error ? Please help me .

Comment: Try adding datatype in the Ajax.

Comment: How can I do that  ?

Comment: `dataType:"text",` try adding this.

Comment: One more thing, i suspect the `request.getParameter()` would get the `post`ed values.

Comment: adding this dataType:"text" ,But I am getting the same error .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16993961/1059101 go through this. May be this could help.

Comment: I need post value . @jai